# Flickering(not smooth movement) while scrolling up using md-virtual-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

in my abc.html I am using to format each object of infiniteItems individually . But the problem is that each object has different size . As the objects in the array are grouped  according to the Date (say no. of items sold on each day, which may be different on each day ).
When i scroll up the items passes away the screen abruptly .

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container  style="height:100vh;width:85%;">
   <div md-virtual-repeat="items in infiniteItems"md-on-demand
      class="repeated-item" flex>
   <div ng-include src="'abc.html'" layout="column" flex="100" ></div>
   </div>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>


//content of abc.html

<div ng-repeat="x in items" > 
 {{x.arr.items_sold}} - {{x.arr.price}}
</div>
structure of an object -
{ id , arr :[ items_sold , price  ] };
```

Comment: If someone is not able to understand anything stated above can write below in comments . I will try to clarify it .

Comment: You may want to look at my previous answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38262143/782358. Also, I found that when I had a very large list I had to refresh the model for all the items to be displayed correctly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what i've read on SO and my own experiences, your issue is not with md-virtual-repeat but with ng-repeat.

ng-repeat is notoriously slow and if you have a rather large dataset is gonna have  performance issues.

I highly recommend you replace ng-repeat with md-virtual-repeat on the abc.html file.